# ¿En qué casos la "nn" del latín se convirtió en "ñ"? ¿Cuándo se mantuvo?

Tags: etimología, ortografía, historia, letras, latín

Descubrí hace poco la palabra *hogaño*:

> [**hogaño**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=KYGRhQf)
>   Tb. ogaño, p. us.
>   **Del lat. *hoc anno* 'en este año'.**
>   1. adv. dem. En la época actual. La historia que narra esa novela bien pudiera acaecer hogaño.
>   2. adv. dem. La época actual. Con más previsión nos hubiéramos ahorrado los problemas de hogaño.
>   3. adv. dem. coloq. p. us. En el año presente.

Cuando unos días después leía sobre connivencia:

> [**connivencia**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=AMSaIOB)
>   **Del lat. tardío *conniventia*, falsa grafía por *coniventia*.**
>   1. f. Disimulo o tolerancia en el superior acerca de las transgresiones que cometen sus subordinados contra las reglas o las leyes bajo las cuales viven.
>   2. f. confabulación.

Como veis, destaco el origen etimológico de cada una de las palabras. Ambas vienen de una palabra latina que contenía *nn*, pero en un caso se mantuvo y en el otro se convirtió en *ñ*.

Sé del [origen del uso de la *ñ*](http://donserifa.com/noticias/sabias-que-el-origen-de-la-ene-es-una-ligadura/). Sin embargo, ¿por qué a veces se convirtió un *nn* en *ñ* y en otras no?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Básicamente dependerá de si la palabra en cuestión es patrimonial (ha evolucionado sin interrupción desde el latín al español) o un (semi)cultismo (se ha introducido en el español *a posteriori*, una vez que los cambios habían dejado de actuar).

Te puede interesar este artículo que escribí hace tiempo sobre la cronología relativa, un concepto relacionado con esto que preguntas: http://www.delcastellano.com/2014/07/25/cronologia-relativa-filologia/

Comment: Caramba, qué bueno tener un artículo tan pertinente al respecto. Lo leeré, ¡gracias! Nótese también que para que la respuesta sea completa -y lo siga siendo si el enlace fallara-, sería interesante que copiaras sus partes más relevantes.

Comment: Pues una vez leído el artículo me quito el sombrero ante él. La _cronología relativa_ tiene mucho sentido.