# Palabras específicas para períodos de tiempo presentes, pasados y futuros

Tags: solicitud-de-término, historia, tiempo

Al hilo de la palabra *hogaño* [descubierta por fedorqui](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/17689/12637) hace poco, me dio por pensar si existían palabras que, al igual que las hay que expresan el día actual, el anterior y el posterior, expresaran lo mismo pero con los años. Y ya puestos, para otros períodos de tiempo como semanas o meses.

Así pues, tendríamos:

> **Días:** ayer / hoy / mañana
>
> **Semanas:** ??? / ??? / ???
>
> **Meses:** ??? / ??? / ???
>
> **Años:** [antaño](http://dle.rae.es/?id=2lbJ8n6) / [hogaño](http://dle.rae.es/?id=KYGRhQf) / ???

¿Es posible rellenar los huecos con palabras que existan o hayan existido en algún momento de la historia del español?

Comment: anteayer? pasado mañana?

Comment: @chapelo la pregunta está restringida a palabras que expresen una unidad de tiempo antes o después de la actual.

Comment: ¿[mañaño](http://forum.wordreference.com/threads/%C2%BFma%C3%B1a%C3%B1o-como-tr%C3%ADade-de-anta%C3%B1o-y-hoga%C3%B1o.3077647/)? Aunque parece que la respuesta es que este término... _ño_ existe.

Comment: @fedorqui la pregunta está hecha a sabiendas de que la respuesta puede ser un simple "no" y ya está... aunque un poco de argumentación para el no tampoco estaría mal.

Comment: Ya... pero pica la curiosidad descubrir nuevas palabras. Yo no sé más que _pasada_ y _que viene/siguiente_ para el antes/después. De todos modos, en el [diccionario inverso](http://dirae.es/) que nos descubriste el otro día y encontré [_otraño_](http://dle.rae.es/?id=RLHePYm)

Comment: @fedorqui yo sé que se puede usar "[corriente](http://dle.rae.es/?id=AzWFsYQ)" para el mes actual: _la inscripción se realizó el día 16 del corriente_. Es un adjetivo para semana, mes, año o siglo, pero se puede usar como sustantivo en el caso de mes o año.

Comment: It may be of interest to know that English shares this lack of specific words. I have no idea why. In very old business letters you can find the abbreviation _inst._ (= corriente), ult. and prox. referring to the months but as far as I know we never had specific words for weeks or years.

Answer (score 1):

Aunque "hogaño" existe, creo que nunca la he visto en un libro en español (excepto diccionarios).   Yo usaría "actualidad" o "actualmente" o alguno de sus derivados en lugar de "hogaño"

Comment: Sí, de hecho la RAE ya indica que [_hogaño_](http://dle.rae.es/?id=KYGRhQf) (y _ogaño_) es un coloquial poco usado.

Comment: **Hogaño** aparece en el Quijote, y en al menos un conocido refrán español ("En los nidos de antaño, no hay pájaros hogaño"). [CVC1](https://cvc.cervantes.es/lengua/refranero/ficha.aspx?Par=58728&Lng=0) [CVC2](https://cvc.cervantes.es/lengua/refranero/ficha.aspx?Par=58728&Lng=0)