# ¿Qué suena como "antaño" pero viene a significar justo lo contrario?

Tags: solicitud-de-término, palabras-raras, tiempo, antónimos, identificación-de-término

Hoy, oyendo un podcast comentando noticias de corte político en España, he escuchado una frase que venía a decir:

> [...] al igual que los curas de antaño se resistían a perder sus privilegios educativos, los de **abaño**<sup>*</sup> tampoco parecen por la labor.

Es la primera vez que oigo la palabra (¿*abaño*?) y no he conseguido encontrarla en el DRAE o en internet. Sabiendo que no conozco la ortografía exacta de la misma he buscado varias combinaciones, con y sin hache y con be o uve, siempre sin éxito. ¿Habré oído mal?

La frase en cuestión proviene de [este podcast](https://youtu.be/LdmUMkXLmqY?t=1410), que comienza alrededor del minuto 23:30 (y la palabra "rara" se pronuncia alrededor del 23:40).

Para mí esta palabra suena como "abaño" u "obaño", y en lugar de significar *de o en un tiempo pasado* como significa *[antaño](https://dle.rae.es/?w=anta%C3%B1o)*, vendría a significar *en el tiempo actual*.

¿Cuál es esta palabra?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

La palabra que buscas es:

> [**hogaño, ogaño**](https://www.lexico.com/es/definicion/hogano)
>
> *adverbio*
>
> En este año o en esta época, en oposición a antaño.

Comment: [hogaño (también ogaño, poco usado) "En la época actual"](https://dle.rae.es/hoga%C3%B1o?m=form). Gracias! No sé por qué esa "g" me sonaba a mi como una "b".

Comment: @Diego anda mira, estaba buscando palabras que se pudieran escribir tanto con _h_ inicial como sin ella, y aquí me habéis dado una. Otra que he encontrado es _hiniesta/iniesta_.

Comment: Por cierto, la palabra _hogaño_ es una [vieja](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/17689/12637) [conocida](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/17694/12637) del sitio. :-)

Comment: @Charlie pensé lo mismo, vieja conocida que ya pronto dejará de ser [tag:palabras-raras] para nosotros :)