# ¿Es "borlaco" una palabra inventada?

Tags: palabras-raras

Mis hijos están viendo una serie de dibujos animados llamada "Green Eggs and Ham", basada en los libros de Dr. Seuss.

En varios momentos de la serie los personajes necesitan usar monedas (o dinero) al que siempre se refieren como "borlacos". No he estado viendo la serie con ellos, pero las monedas siempre eran de una forma extraña y con un valor nominal de una unidad. Cuando lo vi por primera vez, los personajes estaban en una especie de feria, y usaban los "borlacos" para participar en las atracciones, por lo que pensé que "borlaco" era una traducción de "token" o similar

> **Token coin**, a small, flat, round piece of metal or plastic that can sometimes be used instead of money 
>  
>   **Casino token**, also known as a casino chip, check, cheque, or gaming chip

Pero en otro momento de la serie, los personajes salen de la feria y siguen usando los "borlacos" para conseguir otros bienes.

La serie no es solo de dibujos animados, sino que de vez en cuando presenta palabras inventadas para algunos personajes (como animales), y sospecho que "borlaco" puede ser un intento de traducción al español para alguna palabra inventada en inglés.

No he conseguido encontrar ni "borlaco" ni "vorlaco" ni el el diccionario de la real academia ni en el de americanismos.

¿Puedo asumir por tanto que "borlaco" es una palabra inventada? ¿O es algún tipo de jerga que no viene recogida en el diccionario?

[image]

> "tres tiros por un *borlaco*"

Netflix's Green Eggs and Ham, Season 1, Episode 6 "Box". Aprox. 14:36

Answer (score 7):

¿No será *morlaco*? Una de las acepciones del [DRAE](https://dle.rae.es/morlaco) cuadraría

> [morlaco](https://dle.rae.es/morlaco) 
>   3. m. pl. Bol., El Salv., Méx. y Perú. **dinero** (‖ moneda corriente).

Comment: Buen intento, pero desgraciadamente no. En este caso no estoy _teniente_, como con la preguntas de ["hogaño"](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/32792/5481). Es efectivamente "Borlaco" con "b". He actualizado mi pregunta con una captura de pantalla. En cualquier caso, esta es una aportación interesante. Gracias. Me pregunto si entonces su intención era hacer algo que sonase a "morlaco" pero fuese distinto, como si los personajes dijesen "Bonedas" en lugas de "monedas".

Answer (score 3):

> ¿Puedo asumir por tanto que "borlaco" es una palabra inventada? ¿O es algún tipo de jerga que no viene recogida en el diccionario?

En Iberoamérica existen numerosas formas de llamar al dinero, una de ellas es precisamente "borlacos", una variación de la palabra "morlaco".

En la letra del Tango, "Mano a Mano" de (Julio Sosa) Música: Carlos Gardel y José Razzano, Letra: Celedonio Esteban Flores;

> hoy sos toda una bacana, la vida te ríe y canta,
> los morlacos del otario los tirás a la marchanta
> como juega el gato maula con el mísero ratón.

cuando hacen una interpretación de las palabras dudosas aparece "Morlaco" con la siguiente descripción;

- Bacana: Femenino de bacán: Mujer que vive entre el lujo y las comodidades.
- Percanta: Mujer joven, particularmente la de condición humilde.
- **Morlacos**: Billetes de banco, dinero. «Borlacos» es una grafía poco usada, más reciente.
- Otario: Tonto. En este caso, el que paga todos los gastos.
- A la marchanta: Una forma de repartir a un grupo de muchachos monedas o golosinas, arrojándoselas de a puñados. Por analogía, una forma de despilfarrar el dinero.
- Maula: Cobarde; aquél que se aprovecha de su superioridad ante la víctima.

---

Por otra parte, no quedándome satisfecho intente investigar un poco más;

Aquí dejo un extracto recogido en el periódico **Diario de Colima**, del día Jueves 19 de Octubre de 2006 Año 53, Número 17,704, Colima, México, donde el dinero también recibe el nombre de pechereques y se habla de 10.000 borlacos.

> Lo que sí muy a título personal, no es de mi agrado el que el premio se divida en cinco elementos, respeto la decisión del jurado, muy honorable, pero como que me gusta más la adrenalina que sienten los candidatos el saberse que será sólo uno o dos los que se repartirán la marmaja de los 50 mil pechereques, pero en fin, 10 mil borlacos son buenos para cada uno...

Por tanto, no es una palabra inventada, siendo más bien una variante más actual de la voz, "Morlaco".

Comment: ¡Buena respuesta, Diego! Fíjate que edité un poco el formato: cuando citamos, usamos un bloque de texto para que así se vea mejor. Del mismo modo que es común en la red Stack Exchange no añadir saludos ni firmas ni nada, para dejar solamente lo esencial en las publicaciones.